# Swift 2 Using Predicate can't get any result on my filter

Tags: swift, predicate

What am I doing wrong ?

```
import UIKit
var values:NSMutableArray  = []
let url = NSURL(string: "URL")  // PHP JSON Result
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

var searchtext = "ROYAL"

let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[cd] %@", searchtext)
let filteredCars = values.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
```

Comment: please show your json response.

Comment: I always get  [] as result

Comment: In which key you want to check that "Royal" is `contain` or not? Because there is no `ROYAL` in your response.

Comment: Hello @Joseluis. Please [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.Vendor contains[cd] %@ OR SELF.vendor contains[cd] %@ OR SELF.email contains[cd] %@", searchtext, searchtext, searchtext)
let filteredCars = values.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
```

You need to add `Key` in which you want to filter the text.
Hope this will help you.